# Button not working when its superview is auto centered

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am using PureLayout to layout a custom view to be displayed whenever there's a network error/timeout. This custom view is called "ErrorView" and contains 2 labels (title and message), and a retry button ("Try again").

However, when I auto center the custom error view in the view controller's view, the retry button (with the label "Try again") simply stops working. It no longer reacts to any touch events.

Here's the custom "ErrorView" class:

```
import UIKit
import PureLayout

class ErrorView: UIView {

    var contentView: UIView!

    var titleLabel: UILabel!
    var subTitleLabel: UILabel!
    var tryAgainButton: UIButton!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    public func setup() {
        contentView = UIView()
        contentView.backgroundColor = .red

        contentView.autoSetDimension(.width, toSize: 300, relation: .lessThanOrEqual)
        contentView.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: 200, relation: .lessThanOrEqual)

        self.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.autoCenterInSuperview()

        titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title2)
        titleLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        titleLabel.text = "Failed to load this screen"
        contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        titleLabel.autoAlignAxis(.vertical, toSameAxisOf: contentView)
        titleLabel.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .top, of: contentView, withOffset: 16)
        titleLabel.autoPinEdge(.left, to: .left, of: contentView, withOffset: 16)
        titleLabel.autoPinEdge(.right, to: .right, of: contentView, withOffset: -16)

        subTitleLabel = UILabel()
        subTitleLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        subTitleLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        subTitleLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        subTitleLabel.text = "Please contact support."
        contentView.addSubview(subTitleLabel)
        subTitleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        subTitleLabel.autoAlignAxis(.vertical, toSameAxisOf: contentView)
        subTitleLabel.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: titleLabel, withOffset: 16)
        subTitleLabel.autoPinEdge(.left, to: .left, of: titleLabel, withOffset: 16)
        subTitleLabel.autoPinEdge(.right, to: .right, of: titleLabel, withOffset: -16)

        tryAgainButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        tryAgainButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        tryAgainButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        tryAgainButton.autoSetDimensions(to: CGSize(width: 90, height: 40))
        tryAgainButton.backgroundColor = .white
        tryAgainButton.setTitle("Try again", for: .normal)
        tryAgainButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        contentView.addSubview(tryAgainButton)
        tryAgainButton.autoAlignAxis(.vertical, toSameAxisOf: contentView)
        tryAgainButton.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: subTitleLabel, withOffset: 16)
    }

    @objc func buttonAction() {
        print("****** clickable")
    }

}
```

Here's the view controller class where I display the custom error view:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let errorView = ErrorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
        self.view.addSubview(errorView)

        errorView.autoCenterInSuperview() // ---> Problematic code. When removing this, the "Try again" button works.
    }

}
```

This is how the view looks:

[image]

Is there anything I might be missing?

Comment: did you try replace errorView.autoCenterInSuperview() with errorView.center = self.view.center ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the dimensions of the `ErrorView` itself. It has only autoresized `frame`.

Once you call `errorView.autoCenterInSuperview()`, PureLayout also sets `errorView. translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` which makes `frame` to be ignored. `errorView` will be centered, but with zero size. You can still see its contents because you are not clipping it but the button won't receive touches.

I would really really recommend to drop obscure utility libraries like PureLayout. They try to make code short but they also make it unreadable because of the magic they do inside. Writing constraints in code using the native methods is not harder or longer than using PureLayout.

I see several other conflicts in your constraints. For example, you never set hugging/compression resistance priorities for your labels and you set only upper limit for the height. Maybe it would be better to try to design the view in Interface Builder which would validate the constraints for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I initially created a custom view using a .xib file, but I was having issues in getting the button to work. I have no constraint issues using the xib file but the button isn't responding. This is why I tried to create the whole custom view programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Also try using `Debug View Hierarchy` option and check the views. Then you can easily debug the views situation

Answer (score 0):

Try to center your error view in viewDidLayoutSubviews

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        errorView.center = self.view.center
    }
```